# BASH: Trying to continue a string on another line without introducing white space

Tags: string, bash, echo, continue

I have a BASH script with a condition similar to this one:

```
dirImg="/var/log/junk"
sizeLimitMsg="1 gig"

if [ 0 == "$fileSize1" ];then
    echo "All directories under $dirImg are within the allowed\
    $sizeLimitMsg size limit" >> $emailBody
else
    #do something else
fi
```

It produces output with extra white space:

```
All directories under /var/log/junk are within the allowed   1 gig size limit
```

I'm guessing the extra and unwanted white space is coming from indenting the variable $sizeLimitMsg in the conditional above.

Is there anyway I can both continue that line and indent that code without getting the extra and unwanted white space?

Comment: Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include the indentation into the quotes:

```
echo "All directories under $dirImg are within the allowed" \
     "$sizeLimitMsg size limit"
```

Comment: but, `echo "ThereIsAnExtra" \ ` (newline) `"space."` writes `ThereIsAnExtra space.` to stdout.

Comment: @AnaNimbus: So remove the space before \.

Comment: As @choroba pointed out: `echo "IsThereAnExtra"\ ` (newline) `"Space?"` writes `IsThereAnExtraSpace?` to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
printf "%s %s\n" "All directories under ${dirImg} are within the allowed" \
    "${sizeLimitMsg} size limit" >> "${emailBody}"
```

Comment: Or perhaps `printf 'All directories under %s are within the %i size limit\n' "$dirImg" "$sizeLimitMsg"` perhaps with an escaped newline after the format string if you like.

Comment: @tripleee I agree that is a nicer format. Trying to defend my worse format: I am afraid the OP will try to add random text in the format string and will change the message into `printf "All directories under %s are safe under the %s % limit\n" "${dirImg}" "${percUsageAllowed}"` without escaping `%`.